# DRY for constants used both in .NET code and web.config

Tags: .net, web-config, log4net, dry, event-log

I have a Web app which requires a custom installer (to be run using `installutil`) that registers an event source for the event log. This installer code includes a constant (specifically, the name of the event source) which is also repeated in the `web.config` file.

Is there a way I can define this constant in one place (as per the "DRY" principle)?

*For more background: This is for a log4net event log appender, which requires an installer to prevent permission issues as per [this log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-EventLog).*

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to the general problem at all, but I solved this particular case by writing a custom log4net appender just so that it can be initialized in code instead of through the config file:

```
public sealed class EzeReportingEventLogAppender : EventLogAppender
{
    public EzeReportingEventLogAppender()
    {
        Layout = new PatternLayout(Configuration.EventLogPatternLayout);
        LogName = Configuration.EventLogName;
        ApplicationName = Configuration.EventLogApplicationName;
    }
}
```

And in web.config (no longer includes `applicationName`):

```
<appender name="FatalAppender" type="EzeReporting.EzeReportingEventLogAppender">
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```